# Image overlay on dynamically filled div without position:absolute

Tags: html, css

I know there has to be a way to do this. Here's my problem. I have dynamically filled divs that rest inside a container div. The dynamically filled divs are propagated by an image and I have them set to `display: inline` so they are nicely ordered. What I can't seem to do is add an overlay on the dynamic divs. Here's a rundown on the code:

```
<div id="container" style="width:800px">
   <div class="dynamic"><a href="#"><img src="" alt="" /></a></div>
   <div class="dynamic"><a href="#"><img src="" alt="" /></a></div>
   <div class="dynamic"><a href="#"><img src="" alt="" /></a></div>
</div>
```

I have the dynamic divs are styled with a background image and the url and img are delivered through a script. What I would like to do is create an overlay image that I can apply to those divs. Using the `position:absolute` doesn't work because they need to flow across the page in a ordered list.

Here's a bit of the code: http://jsfiddle.net/Juccq/

As you can see, it's not really working as expected. I'd like each .dribbble-shots to be lined up nicely, and then have .dribbble-shots-overlay apply the png, respectively. The code works with one instance, but when it gets multiplied, it breaks.

Comment: Try to create a fiddle at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or at least share some necessary CSS to demonstrate your problem and expected result...

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "overlay image"? Can't you place the image as background of the div?

Comment: @Passerby edited with a bit of code.

Comment: @cksum Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Juccq/1/ ?

Comment: @Passerby unfortunately that won't work as it disrupts the `a href` and I'd like to keep the clickable area the entire div. I'm starting to think this actually may not be possible with all the constraints. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use `position:absolute;`, you just have add the css property `pointer-events:none;` to the overlay, but be aware this will not work in IE or Opera.

http://jsfiddle.net/5XqkP/ (fixed up a bit of the CSS too)

Or you could instead try something like this with a bit of javascript:

http://jsfiddle.net/jt8bh/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the overlay image as background, and reduce the opacity of the inline image to 0 on :hover. The inline image will retain its position, and won't break the layout, but the overlay (actually *underlay*) image will be visible.